# AJAX data is sent empty to PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send the id of an element and a value (1,2,3) through ajax to a PHP document that checks if the data is empty (which is always). The two values I'm trying to send are correctly logged on the console though.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

       $('.status-menu-option-1').click(function(){
           changeLabelStatus(1);
       });
       $('.status-menu-option-2').click(function(){
           changeLabelStatus(2);
       });
       $('.status-menu-option-3').click(function(){
           changeLabelStatus(3);
       });
       function changeLabelStatus(status){
           var parent = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
           console.log(status);
           console.log(parent);
           $.ajax({ 
               url: 'team/canva_change_label',
               type: "GET",
               data: {
                   status : status,
                   row : parent
               },
               success: function(msg) { 
                   if(msg.error) {
                       alert(msg.error_msg);
                       return;             
                   }
               } 
           });

       }
   }
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't point what.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `.closest(selector)` rather than hard-coding the number of parents.

Comment: You're not passing the event into the `changeLabelStatus` method to be used.  You should not rely on the event being a global variable as this is non-standard behavior that not all browsers adhear to.

Comment: @Taplar Please post an answer showing how to do it correctly, so I don't have to.

Comment: Alright, one second.

Comment: @StephenP Where did the op say the data was json, or that ajax == JSON?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.status-menu-option-1').click(function(e){
    changeLabelStatus(e.target, 1);
  });

  $('.status-menu-option-2').click(function(e){
    changeLabelStatus(e.target, 2);
  });

  $('.status-menu-option-3').click(function(e){
    changeLabelStatus(e.target, 3);
  });

  function changeLabelStatus(element, status){
    var parent = $(element).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    console.log(status);
    console.log(parent);

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'team/canva_change_label',
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        status : status,
        row : parent
      },
      success: function(msg) { 
        if(msg.error) {
          alert(msg.error_msg);
          return;             
        }
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

You need to pass in the element that the event resulted from, rather than relying on the event being a global variable, which is not standard behavior for all browsers.

Also, you should be able to use a form of `closest(selector)` instead of all those chained parent calls, but without seeing the markup I can't suggest a proper selector.

Comment: This helped too but the real mistake was that I was treating data as a JSON object/array in the PHP function, so in this sense @StephenP was right.